# How to use having clause on relationship with sequelize node

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have 2 models, `business` and `documents` in a `1:n` relationship, i want to filter the `business` in two ways,

1. `business` that has `documents` where every `document.due_balance` is greater than 0
2. `business` that has `documents` where every `document.due_balance` is equals to 0

I want to make something like this

```
select
    A.name, B.due_balance, sum(B.due_balance) as total_due_balance
from
    business A
inner join documents B ON A.id = B.business_id
group by A.id
having total_due_balance > 0;

select
    A.name, B.due_balance, sum(B.due_balance) as total_due_balance
from
    business A
inner join documents B ON A.id = B.business_id
group by A.id
having total_due_balance = 0;
```

these will get me what i want, the problem, is that the previus code was made with sequelize ORM, and i can't change it, something like this

const businesses = await db.business.paginate({
    attributes: [
    ...
    ],
    where: {
    ... //bunch of where
    },
    page: parseInt(params.page, 10) || 1,
    paginate: parseInt(params.limit, 10) || 10,
});

here is where the problem begins, i don't know how to join the tables and use the having to filter it, i have tried addind this

```
let toInclude;
if (params.contactability === 'with_balance') {
    toInclude = {
        include : [
            {
                attributes: [
                    [db.Sequelize.fn('sum', db.Sequelize.col('due_balance')), 'total_due_balance'],
                ],
                model: db.document,
                as: 'documents',
                having: db.Sequelize.where(db.Sequelize.fn('sum', db.Sequelize.col('due_balance')), {
                    $gt: 0,
                }),
            },
        ],
    };
} else if(params.contactability === 'without_balance') {
    toInclude = {
        include : [
            {
                attributes: [
                    [db.Sequelize.fn('sum', db.Sequelize.col('due_balance')), 'total_due_balance'],
                ],
                model: db.document,
                as: 'documents',
                having: db.Sequelize.where(db.Sequelize.fn('sum', db.Sequelize.col('due_balance')), {
                    $eq: 0,
                }),
            },
        ],
    };
} else {
    toInclude = {};
}
const businesses = await db.business.paginate({
    attributes: [
    ...
    ],
    where: {
    ...
    },
    ...toInclude,
    page: parseInt(params.page, 10) || 1,
    paginate: parseInt(params.limit, 10) || 10,
});
```

but that does not work at all, how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

1. I don't think HAVING will work without GROUP.
2. I would move the having clause outside the include section and use the AS aliases.

So, roughly:

`group: ['id'],  // and whatever else you need
 having : { 'documents.total_balance_due' : {$eq : 0 }}`

(Making some guesses vis the aliases)

Answer (score 1):

> To filter the date from joined table which uses groupby as well, you can make use of HAVING Property, which is accepted by Sequelize.

So with respect to your question, I am providing the answer.

You can make use of this code:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

let searchQuery = {
    attributes: {
        // include everything from business table and total_due_balance as well
        include: [[Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.col('documents.due_balance')), 'total_due_balance']]
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: Documents, // table, which you require from your defined model
            as: 'documents', // alias through which it is defined to join in hasMany or belongsTo Associations
            required: true, // make inner join
            attributes: [] // select nothing from Documents table, if you want to select you can pass column name as a string to array
        }
    ],
    group: ['business.id'], // Business is a table
    having: ''
};

if (params.contactability === 'with_balance') {
    searchQuery.having = Sequelize.literal(`total_due_balance > 0`);
} else if (params.contactability === 'without_balance') {
    searchQuery.having = Sequelize.literal(`total_due_balance = 0`);
}

Business // table, which you require from your defined model
    .findAll(searchQuery)
    .then(result => { 
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Note : Change model name or attributes according to your requirement.

Hope this will help you or somebody else!